# Deriving benifit from Chametz on pesach

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, hanaah-benefit

Someone asked this and I can't find the question anymore but i found a source to answer this.

Can one derive benefit from chametz on Pesach?

Comment: In the future, you can always ask on the chat if anyone recalls where this question is.

Answer (score -2):

This is not Psak Halacha, just what a rishon says, but no one holds this as psak halacha.

Rashi on Avodah Zara 74a says
תרתי אית ליה דבר שבמנין ואיסורי הנאה. דאיכא תרתי לחשיבותא דחשיב איסור דידהו הוא דלא בטיל אבל חמץ פרוסה בפסח הואיל ואין דרכו למנות בטיל ומשליך אחד מהן לנהר והשאר נותן לכלבו וחתיכת נבילה אע"ג דדבר שבמנין הוא כיון דלאו איסור הנאה הוא בטלה ברובא וחדא שדי לכלבים ואינך שרו באכילה

Since there are two things that are important, and because of the  factors: [it is a] דבר שבמנין and [it is] אסור בהנאה, therefore bitul חמץ פרוסה בפסח by throwing one piece into the river and one piece to the dog. The chametz is assur behanah

Since you can give it to the dog it shows it is not assur behanah.

The other part of Rashi is impossible to understand without the Gemara so i am explaining it outside.
the Gemara gives a case where you have 3 hot dogs and then a non-kosher one fell in. This Rashi is not quoted in Shulchan Aruch regarding this part. 
Rashi - when something is בטל ברוב it's still assur to eat it.you first must throw out the # of אסור  pieces first then you can eat it[rashi's example is giving it to a dog or throwing it in the river